# simple_form and i18n of DATE::abbr_daynames

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following line to obtain a select box with all the week days

```
= f.select :day, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.each_with_index.to_a
```

I need the week days translated according to my locale. I am not sure why it is not working.

I am using the `simpleform` gem for the form builder.

I went on to debug in the console and discovered:

```
I18n.t Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.each_with_index.to_a
 => "translation missing: es.Sun.0"
```

I am not sure why this is happening since my es.yml file contains:

```
es:
  Sun: 
    0: Dom
```

I am also wondering if there is another way of getting a select box with the week days. This way of writing the es.yml entries feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in console try

```
I18n.t(:"date.day_names").each_with_index.to_a
```

and in simple form

```
= f.select :day, @builder.select(attribute_name, I18n.t(:"date.day_names").each_with_index.to_a)
```